# OnItemClickListener() is not working in api 16

Tags: android

I have a listview which works perfectly on all android versions except Jellybean android version.In jellybean android version(api 16) the `onItemClickListener()` is not triggering.

here is my listview row xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/frontpage_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


<ImageView android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewicons" />



<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/binImage"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_grey_100_24dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewicons"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

I am implementing listview on a `WindowManger` in service so I coded it like this:

```
listAdapter:

class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drawable>

{

    ListAdapter() {

        super(Window.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, iconL);
    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {



        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Window.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon,null);
        image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewicons);
        image.setImageDrawable(iconL.get(position));
        textView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(finalPackage.get(position));
        Trash=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.binImage);











        return row;

    }

}

//listview creation

listadapter=new ListAdapter();

listView.setId(listId);
    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
```

can anyone solve this problem.`Onitemclicklistener` is working fine on android kitkat version onwards, the problem is occuring only in jellybean version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add clickable="true" in your root layout view